# Remove encoded question mark from URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mediawiki, wiki, url-encoding

Hi I started a fact check wiki where each fact check page page ends in a question mark, for example:

http://wecheck.org/wiki/Did_Mitt_Romney_ever_work_as_a_garbage_collector%3F

But when I share this link on many sites including Facebook by pasting it into a comment box, it strips the %3f (thinking it's the start of a query string I guess) making the link unreachable. I have to use bit.ly to connect to the link which is inconvenient and a problem for novice users.

I think I may be able to use mod-rewrite to take the %3F off. My current rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

How would I modify them to strip out the %3F ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you want to strip out the `%3F`. Mediawiki has its own routing so if you mess with the title names, you're more likely break something than fix anything. You need to modify your media-wiki to either disallow pages with a `?` at the end, or add a module or wiki bot to go through all the pages, and if there's a page that ends with `?`, create a `#REDIRECT [[]]` page without the `?` and point it to the page with the `?`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Wouldn't it be simpler to leave the question mark off the file name and add it <page title header> + "?" in the PHP file for the page somewhere?

UPDATE: I realized that this would mean that every page, even ones that are not questions, would have a ? added to them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create pages that do not have question marks at the end and then set

```
$wgRestrictDisplayTitle = false; in LocalSettings.php
```

and use the following magicwords in the page markup:

```
{{DISPLAYTITLE:{{PAGENAME}}?}}
```

You can see an example here: http://wecheck.org/wiki/Question_Mark_Problem